# What is the significance of Local(No Agent), standalone & java Agent in ODI.

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

What is the significance of Local(No Agent), standalone & java Agent in ODI.

why we need all these agents . Please explain the significance of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The agent is what generates the code represented your mappings, starts and monitors the execution and logs results in the repository.

- Local (No Agent) : This is a lightweight agent that is part of ODI Studio, for testing purposes while developing. It is only started when ODI Studio is open so it comes with some limitations. For instance you can't schedule an execution.
- Standalone Agent : This is a standalone java agent that runs as a background daemons on your server.
- JEE Agent : This agent is installed on a Weblogic Server. You can install more than one to have high-availability and load balancing. The agent can be monitored to OEM. This is the preferred architecture if you have mission-critical integration jobs.

More info in this excellent blog post from the Oracle A-Team : http://www.ateam-oracle.com/odi-agents-standalone-jee-and-colocated/